# mostrar en twig el resultado de una consulta JOIN en Symfony

Tags: symfony3, join, twig, symfony, dql

Tengo 2 tablas las cuales no están relacionadas por `ORM` por lo cual hago el `JOIN` de la siguiente manera:

```
$dql="Select u, o
      from BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN BackendBundle:Users u
      WITH o.userid=u.id";
$query=$em->createQuery($dql);
```

Al momento de enviar la consulta a twig para mostrarlo en pantalla me muestra un error.

Este es el código en `twig`:

```
{% for ordenes in pagination %}
  <td>{{ ordenes.orderid }}</td>
  <td>{{ ordenes.orderdate|date("Y-m-d") }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Y el error es este:

`Neither the property "orderid" nor one of the methods "orderid()", "getorderid()"/"isorderid()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "BackendBundle\Entity\Users"`

Si ejecuto en `twig` este código:

```
{{dump(pagination)}}
```

Me muestra correctamente lo que devuelve la consulta:

```
  #currentPageNumber: 3
  #numItemsPerPage: 20
  #items: array:40 [▼
    0 => Orders {#522 ▼
      -orderid: 158
      -orderdate: DateTime {#476 ▶}
      -ordernumber: "FFFFFFFFFFF"
      -customername: "UUUUUUUUUUUU"
      -customeraddress: "OOOOOO"
      -countrycode: "US"
      -shippingaddress: "PPPPPP"
      -status: "Ordered"
      -subtotal: "5.00"
      -shippingcost: "2.82"
      -tax: "0.00"
      -discount: "0.00"
      -totalorder: "7.82"
      -shippingcarrier: "Fedex"
      -userid: "1206"
    }
    1 => Users {#525 ▼
      -id: 1206
      -username: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com"
      -yourname: null
      -firstname: "GGGG"
      -lastname: "IIIIII"
      -middlename: ""
      -address: "oooooooooo"
      -address2: ""
      -apartment: ""
      -pobox: ""
      -city: "Monsey"
      -state: "NY"
      -zipcode: "88888888"
      -country: "USA"
      -countrycode: "US"
      -email: "xxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com"
      -datein: DateTime {#521 ▶}
    }
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo mostrar este resultado en twig???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de revisar e intentar resolver este problema. Finalmente cree la relación en los archivos yml entre las 2 tablas de esta manera:

```
//BackendBundle\Entity\Orders:
indexes:
    fk_order_user1_idx:
        columns:
            - user_id
......
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Users
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            user_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

También en la Entidad:

```
//Orders.php
/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
private $user;
......
/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Users $user
 *
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUser(\BackendBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

Actualizo la base de datos:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Y realizo la consulta de esta manera:

```
$dql="SELECT u, o
      FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN o.user u";
$query=$em->createQuery($dql);
```

Comment: Así está solucionado? Si es así pon tu respuesta como correcta por si le sirve de ayuda a otro.

Comment: Así se arreglo pero stackoverflow solo permite que acepte mi respuesta después de 2 días.